# Почему, для задания размерности массива в классе, должно использовать константную статическую переменную,а не просто константную

Tags: c++

```
struct A{
static const int SZ{0};
int mass[SZ];
};
```

без static не работает

Comment: подумайте о sizeof такой структуры.

Answer (score 3):

Наличие инициализации поля `SZ` вводит в заблуждение. Если это поле не статическое, то даже при наличии инициализации значение этому полу присваивается только в момент создания конкретного экземпляра этого класса. Причем оно может быть разным у разных экземпляров. Соответственно во время компиляции размер массива не известен.

`const` модификатор для нестатического поля указывает, что значение поля не может изменяться после инициализации конкретного экземпляра класса, а не что оно не может быть разным. Пример:

```
struct Foo
{
    const int x{0};
};

Foo f1{};
Foo f2{42};
cout << f1.x << endl; // выводит 0
cout << f2.x << endl; // выводит 42
```

Comment: Как оно может быть разным, если оно `const`?

Comment: @Herrgott Обновил ответ с пояснением для `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Потомучтно рамер sizeof(A) должен быть определен на момент компиляции. Без static можно задать любое значение SZ в конструкторе объекта.
Например:

```
struct A
{
    A(int v) : SZ(v) {}
    const int SZ{0}
    int mass[SZ];
};

void main() 
{
    A a(5); // <- сколько байт выделять под объект на стеке?
}
```